# Apache URL masking

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

I need to access **http://www.domain.com/uri-path-to-resource.rsc** in the browser, but to display the content from **http://shop.domain.com/uri-path-to-resource.rsc**.
Unfortunately ProxyPass could not be used in the .htaccess file and I have no idea how to accomplish it.

Any ideas are more than welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^uri-path-to-resource.rsc$ /absolutepath/private_html/shop.domain/uri-path-to-resource.rsc [L]
```

Change the example path to the absolute path for your shop.domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule

```
RewriteRule ^uri-path-to-resource.rsc$ http://shop.domain.com/uri-path-to-resource.rsc [L]
```

Comment: Yes, I though of that, but it will not do the trick in my case.

Comment: The www. domain's document root is the ~/public_hml, but for the shop.domain is ~/private_html/shop.domain/